# Find critical points of the function $x^2+4xy+4y^2+x^3+2x^2y+y^4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find critical points of the function $x^2+4xy+4y^2+x^3+2x^2y+y^4$

I found that $(0,0)$ is a critical point but I couldn't able to define it whether it'll be maximum or minimum. What are the other critical points of the function? What should I do now?

Comment: If I have done no mistake in calculating the derivative with regards to x and y, then Wolframalpha, gives a 2nd solution, which does not seem you can come up with so easily and more likely have to approximate numerically. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2B4y%2B3x%5E2%2B4xy%3D0+and+4x%2B8y%2B2x%5E2%2B4y%5E3%3D0 Besides that, you would need the Hessian matrix to check if you have a local maximum or minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function $f(x,y)$. For a point $(a,b)$ to be a critical point,the  partial derivatives at that point have to zero. 
$$ \partial_x f(x,y) = 0 ,\partial_y f(x,y) = 0$$

Where $\partial_{x_i} f(x_1, x_2, ..) = \cfrac{\partial f(x_1, x_2..)}{\partial x_i} $

Define $$ D = 
        \begin{vmatrix}
     \partial_x^2 f(x,y)& \partial_{xy} f(x,y) \\
     \partial_{yx} f(x,y) & \partial_y^2 f(x,y) 
         \end{vmatrix} 
        $$

Now, If a point, say $P(a,b)$ is a critical point then there are three possible cases:

1. Local Maximum: If $D \gt 0$ and $\partial_x^2 f(x,y) < 0$
2. Local Minimum: If $D \gt 0$ and $\partial_x^2 f(x,y) > 0$
3. Saddle point:  If $D < 0$

Now, having knowledge of these, I hope you can solve your problem,now.

Comment: Can you help me to find out the critical points of it by solving those 1st order partials diff equns since I actually know the process that you have told but the difficulty is that I couldn't able to do that by paper and pencil. That's why I need  help to figure out those critical points exactly by paper and pencil.

Comment: Okay, I will, can you do the second part of the question i.e. finding the nature of critical points?

Comment: Yes sir..I can do that

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the nature of the critical point $(0,0)$:

The Hessian matrix at that point represents the quadratic part of the power series for the expression at that point, which is $x^2+4xy+4y^2=(x+2y)^2$. That would make $(0,0)$ a degenerate critical point because that expression has its minimum value $0$ at every point of the line $x+2y=0$.

Also including the cubic part of the original expression gives $x^2+4xy+4y^2+x^3+2x^2y=(x+2y)(x+x^2+2y)$, which for any fixed value of $x$ is negative when $-x^2-x<2y<-x$ with a minimum value of $-\frac{x^4}4$ where $2y=-x-\frac{x^2}2$. That would make $(0,0)$ a saddle point.

So the final question is wether also including the quartic part $y^4$ will still leave points with negative values arbitrarily close to $(0,0)$ or wether it will turn $(0,0)$ into a local minimum.